# How to browse a file in raml language?

Tags: spring-mvc, mule, raml

I want to browse a file in RAML like the tool postman:
[image]

But when I write in RAML language is not support for that:

```
body:
  multipart/form-data:
    formParameters:
      file:
        description: The file to be uploaded
        required: true
        type: file
```

And It doesn't have button "Browse", so I don't know how to attach a file to endpoint:
[image]

Comment: I hope I am wrong but I think API console (Mule's RAML documentation generator) does not have yet the browse file functionality. You may have to input the file contents instead.. I suggest to test those endpoints with file param using Postman for the mean time.. Also, I think you can request this feature on their Github repo, https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console/issues.

Comment: Thank for your information Tyrone :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi ganninu93, I've not found yet :(

Answer (score 1):

This is missing in the API Console as [the spec for the `file` type](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/raml-0.8.md#type) is clear on the necessity to support file uploads for RAML tooling:

> file  (Applicable only to Form properties)
>   Value is a file. Client generators SHOULD use this type to handle file uploads correctly.

As Tyrone suggested, open a bug in GitHub: https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console/issues