# Browse files in RAML - workaround

Tags: file-upload, raml, file-browser

I have done some research and it appears that the RAML console does not support the functionality to browse for files. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220405/how-to-browse-a-file-in-raml-language), [link2](https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console/issues/173), [link3](https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console/issues/199).

Is there perhaps an unofficial workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Very good question. Doesn't seem there is one, but we are working on a new console that will probably contain that OOTB. What I would do is to just up vote https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console/issues/199.